# How to pass index value and get name from array response angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

onRowClick function, i am getting index id.

Comment: store data in global variable i.e. tagPolicies and use tagPolicies[rowid].name to get the name

Comment: i edited my question, how i find name of column from index value..

Comment: what is your array ? show an eg of a a proper format

Comment: added scrnshot of my array data..https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK7pf.png

Comment: i want to find name from data using row index..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below :

```
onRowClick($event) {
    const indexid= $event;
    this.tagPolicesArray['records'].map(function(item, index){
         if(index == indexid){

          console.log(item['name']); ----------------> Here you will get your required name

         }
     });
  }
```

Comment: i m geting below error ERROR TypeError: "this.tagPolicesArray.map is not a function"

Comment: I am assuming that tagPoliciesArray is an array  ? Is it ?

Comment: i m gettting data as per attached image..records are my data in image

Comment: Why have you mentioned this     this.tagPolicesArray;
 then ?  "I want to fetch name from tagPolicesArray Array based on index id."

Comment: sorry my mistake..

Comment: your object name is rajnikant in your image ? Is it right or anything else it is ?

Comment: object name is {…}..i mean empty object...rajnikant is just for console.log to identify the corect object..

Comment: And from where do you get this rajnikant object ? do you store it in a variable or anythin ? Show me what have you console.log to get the object in your image description.

Comment: Have edited the code, try it.!